# What array class has a remove and return object method?

Tags: java, libgdx, iterator

Which libgdx iteratable class has a remove and return method? that will be use in the code below.

```
Array<Entity> entities = new Array<Entity>();
Array<Entity> entitiesToRemove = new Array<Entity>();
Entity entityToRemove = entities.remove(entity);
entitiesToRemove .add(entityToRemove);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no array class that has a remove and return object method, as far as I know. I would solve it like that:

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.size; i++) {
    array.get(i);
    array.removeIndex(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally any queue datastructure have this retrieve and remove feature. In your case a native Java Queue (or a simple LinkedList) would already have the feature, but since you wanted a libgdx class:

[Queue](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/utils/Queue.html)

The functions you would be interested in are:

```
T   removeFirst()
Remove the first item from the queue.

T   removeIndex(int index)
Removes and returns the item at the specified index.

T   removeLast()
Remove the last item from the queue.
```

Comment: exactly, but he asked for an Array class

Comment: The `Array` class already has `pop` and `removeIndex`, which would do the same retrieve&remove logic. I assume he is looking for some alternative, so I described the most typical solution: queues.

Comment: @GergelyBacso the reason I am looking for libgdx remove and return method, because of the `T Object` is used to remove an element, but the `Array` does not contain any of that

Comment: It has that too, it is `removeValue`: https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/utils/Array.html#removeValue-T-boolean-